# Nuget packages not referencing correctly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

At present, I am having a very strange problem I have dapper in a shared project which has been working for ages. I opened up the solution today to do a build and it's refusing to build.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Dapper' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   FuelSageIntergrationDA   tockTransferArgs.cs    1   N/A

You can see from the image below that it is indeed registered via NuGet

[image]

But yet I am still having the above resolve issue I have cleaned my projects and reinstalled from NuGet with no luck

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I get these types of issues if I haven't done a nuget restore, there is a menu from the solution item to perform the restore action. Also you can do `dotnet restore` from the command line in the same directory as your solution/project.

Comment: Have done a restore and eveything their no yellow marks

Comment: @rogue39nin, any update?

Comment: @CherryBu this appeared to be a xarmain bug in their nuget code it appears to be fixed in their lattest release are u facing a simliar issue.